# Can't change size for UIPopover?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I'm writing an app that needs to spawn a popover in order to add a new note. To that end, I have something that does kind of the trick, however, I can't seem to adjust the size of the popover. This is how I'm spawning it:

```
UIButton* btn =sender;
UIViewController* fooTroller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

CGRect rectFoo = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
UIView* fooView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rectFoo];
[fooView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[fooTroller setView:fooView];
popOver =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:fooTroller];

[popOver presentPopoverFromRect:btn.frame
                         inView:self.view
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
                       animated:YES];
```

Any thoughts? It's not respecting the view size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be calling `setView:` on the view controller. Let the view controller setup its own view.

The proper way to size a popover is to either override the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` method of your view controller to return the size or to set the `popoverContentSize` property on the popover.

```
UIButton* btn =sender;
UIViewController* fooTroller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:fooTroller];
popOver.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);

[popOver presentPopoverFromRect:btn.frame
                         inView:self.view
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
                       animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for that. So if I had a custom UI that I wanted in the popover, how would I show it?

Comment: Just like any other screen - you create a custom view controller class with whatever views and logic you need.

Comment: Okay, the view needs to be made programmatically, but I'll research that. Thanks!

Comment: Whether you do it all in code (which is what I do) or use IB, it's the same in the end. You alloc/init the custom view controller and use it in the popover.

Comment: Okay, this is gonna sound stupid... So I have my UIView derived class, and I create a UIViewController instance, how do I init with the custom UIView? The init methods don't account for it...